# how to perform an operation on a selected name from my drop down box

Tags: jquery, html, mysql, ajax, jsp

I want to select a name from my drop down box. for example, say i want to view there details. so i must create a details button and i want to put a join operation query to join two tables. can anyone pls help me by posting a sample code to do this. :'(

i want to do this in jsp page. i dont know javascript, so if anyone giving solution in javascript please give me an detailed solution explaining how it works.

```
  <select name ="StaffName"> <% while(resultset.next()){ %>
  <option value=""><%= resultset.getString(2)%></option>
  <%} 
  %>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input name="Submit" type="button" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

ADDED THIS CODING, PLEASE CHECK

```
  function fetchDBValues(data){
    //Call Your AJAX function here passing the required URL and values.
    <form id="frmMain" name="frmMain">
            var data = "<select name ='StaffName'  onChange='fetchDBValues(this.value)'>"
            <% while(resultset.next()){ %>
            <option value=""><%= resultset.getString(2)%></option></select>
    $.ajax({
        url : 'http://localhost:8080/sample',
        type : "POST",
        async : false,
        success : function fetchDBValues(data) {
            //Sample data

            $("#fillValue").html(data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: what is wrong with the above code

Comment: i want to make that submit button active

Comment: now i have added a ajax coding, referred from net and like what u said. i dont know how to make this coding to work. what changes should b done? can you help?

Comment: so when you are submitting the form,does the select Value is not passing?If not please post the code showing how you are retrieving the parameters.Also in **http://localhost:8080/sample** is sample a servlet?

Comment: i have created database, by connecting to my database I retrieve values.. I want to make that submit button to perform action, do you get me?im not using servlet codings

Answer (score 0):

IF you are looking at executing a select query based on the selected value from this drop down , javascript wont be helpful. Javascript is a client side scripting language.

You will have to either submit your action to a servlet / jsp that has a jdbc connection to the database and perform a SQL. To avoid a page refresh , you could resort to AJAX/JQuery as well.

You could use the following code

```
<head>
 <script>
    function fetchDBValues(pVal){
        //Call Your AJAX function here passing the required URL and values.
    }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="frmMain" name="frmMain">
  <select name ="StaffName" onChange="fetchDBValues(this.value)"> <% while(resultset.next()){ %>
  <option value=""><%= resultset.getString(2)%></option>
  <%} 
  %>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input name="Submit" type="button" value="Submit">
 </form>
 </body>
```

The following link might help you perform the AJAX actions and obtain return values :
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: can u give me a sample coding for that?

Comment: Added the same.pl check.

Comment: sir, im new.. and this is my very first try.. i hav entered the following coding.